# I want to autosort when a change is made on a different sheet, not the active sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have the following JavaScript:

```
  function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "a2:b100";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}
```

This works fine when I input the date manually on the Important Dates sheet.  But I have my formulas and date calculators in a separate sheet called Data.  When the dates change in the Data sheet, even though they pull into the Important Dates sheet, they don't auto-sort.  The only way to sort is to manually put in a date in Column A of the Important Dates sheet and then it sorts.  How can I get the Important Dates sheet to auto sort when a change is made in the Data sheet that pulls into the Important Dates sheet with a function such as "=Data!A3".

FYI, I have tried to change `onEdit` to `onChange` but it no longer sorts at all when I do that.

Comment: How are the changes done in the Data sheet?

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Thanks for the script but you didn't describe what is happening in your spreadsheet. _You_ have a very clear understanding of how your sheets work, linkages, etc - but you didn't include that in your question - we need to know this too.  Would you please edit your question to explain your scenario, your spreadsheet layout, the purpose of the script, the data on each sheet, any other scripts that you have running, and the data on "Important Dates" that is sourced from "Dates".

Comment: Thank you for the response.  While I would love to know the java script that would fix this issue, I resolved it in a very simple way.  I just used the sort function which works for a new sheet that is grabbing info from another stagnant sheet that has the data.